# Java: printing or returning the name of a newly instantiated object in toString

Tags: java

I basically typed this over so it may have some syntax errors, but I was asked to get the height, length, and name of the object in a toString line.  I'm getting the height and length fine, but I don't know how to get the name (rec1 and rec2) into the toString.

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
        Rectangle rec1 = new Rectangle();
        Rectangle rec2 = new Rectangle();

        System.out.println(rec1);
        System.out.println(rec2);
}


Class Rectangle
{
        private double height;
        private double length;
        ***private string name;***

        Public Rectangle()
        {
             height = 8;
             length = 6;
             ***name = this.name***
        }
```

I tried adding a string into the rectangle constructor, but I didn't know what to initialize the string name to.  I left the get and set (we are also mutating height and length) of the height and length out for convenience.

```
        ***public String getName()
        {
             return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name)
        {
             this.name = name;
        }***

        public String toString()
        {
           return (***name*** + height + " " + length);
        }
```

When I used the emphasized lines, the name comes up null.  Am I even on the right track?

Comment: What do you think this does, `name = this.name`?

Comment: You can't (in any reasonable way), they're asking for the name passed in to the `Rectangle`.

Comment: Please post code that at least compiles. There are so many errors in that code that we don't know what you actually tried.

Comment: There is no way whatsoever to get the variable name used in defining the object.  (To say nothing of the fact that multiple variables may refer to the same object.)  You'll have to pass in the string `"rec1"` explicitly.

Comment: It looks like you're confusing the variable name with a name String, and please understand that they are completely different. If you want to print a name, you're going to have to create a String and assign it to the `name` String variable. The object itself has no knowledge of the name(s) of any variables that refer to it, and understand that it can be many many variables. If the object did, which variable would be **the** name?

Comment: I think it keeps the value as it is, which basically does nothing.  I just don't know how to initialize it.

Comment: How to initialize it? The same as any variable. Give the constructor a name parameter, create a String and pass it into the constructor.

Comment: I'm obviously new to java.  So in the instructions they're asking for:    Lastly, it contains a toString method that returns the name of the shape, its length, and its height.         They just want rectangle?

Answer (score 1):

To add the name variable to the String returned by the `toString()` method, just concatenate it with the rest of the `String` returned.

Either make the private `name` field in the `Rectangle` class as you have, or make it public.

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    return ("Rectangle: name = " + name ", height = " + height + ", length = " + length);
}
```

This will solve the issue, as far as I understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

`rec1` and `rec2` are no names of your object and they are also not name fields of your Rectangle class.
They are the names of your local reference variables.

If you need a name in your Rectangle object, then you have to add a field name, and set it with a setter or in the constructor and then append it in the overridden `toString`-method.

But, if you want to see that the object, which you print is a `Rectangle`, then you have to override the toString-Method, as follows:

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    return "Rectangle{ height = " + height + ", length = " + length + "}");
}
```